# unix netstat command to filter output on foreign address

Tags: macos, shell, unix, tcp, netstat

I want to show results of `netstat` for foreign address starting with `54.` for `ESTABLISHED` TCP connections.

This is sample output I am looking for:

```
tcp 0 0 192.168.X.X:42436 54.X.X.70:80 ESTABLISHED -
tcp 0 0 192.168.X.X:51160 54.X.X.73:80 ESTABLISHED -
```

I have tried various commands but nothing comes close or I would list my attempts here, but they wouldn't be helpful.

Is this possible in a single command or do I need to create a script.

Comment: It is always better to show your attempts. Even though it may be wrong or may not be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with `awk`,

```
netstat | awk '$5 ~ /^54/ && $6 ~ /ESTABLISHED/'
```